# What is the OSX, C equivalent for uint32 and uint64?

Tags: c, xcode, macos

I imagine this is a question that has been asked a thousand times but I can't find a straight answer.

I'm trying to port a very short, C function (initially written for Windows) to OSX, using XCode.

I've created an XCode, Terminal application project and I've copied and pasted the code into the project.  XCode is giving me a bunch of errors telling me that the type `uint32` and `uint64` are unknown types.

What are the equivalent value types in OSX?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `uint32_t` and `uint64_t` by importing `stdint.h`.

Answer (score 3):

What you want are the POSIX and C standard integer types. These are what are used on Mac OSX, Linux, Solaris, etc. They are `uint8_t` all the way through `uint64_t`. There are also `int8_t` through `uint8_t`.

Comment: Just as a clarification, by "all the way", this _really_ means all the way: there are available integer types whose size is not a power of two (`int24_t`, `int40_t`, `int48_t`, `int56_t` and their unsigned counterparts).

Comment: @zneak, these need not to be defined. But if such types (with that width) exist on the platform they will be defined.

Answer (score 2):

`uint32_t` and `uint64_t` — both defined in [`stdint.h`](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdint.html) as per the C99 definition.

The others are Microsoft's proprietary solution.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Try these ;-) `UInt32 lala;
UInt64 lolo;`</s>

Misread the question. If you create a terminal only project you won't be linking Cocoa/Foundation and *Carbon*. Within the latter UInt16/32/64 are typedef'ed.

Comment: I think those are Carbon types.